# how to fix Error componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I use react js to create a staycation website, when I want to display the InputNumber and InputDate components I experience an error like the title above, in the componentDidUpdate section, I have tried tweaking the code but it hasn't worked, but when I omit the componentDidUpdate part, the inputdate and inputnumber components run.

this is the input component code Number I have tried the input component works well,:

```js
        import React from "react";
        import propTypes from "prop-types";
        import "./index.scss";
        
        export default function Number(props) {
          const {
            value,
            placeholder,
            name,
            min,
            max,
            prefix,
            suffix,
            isSuffixPlural,
          } = props;
        
          const onChange = (e) => {
            let value = String(e.target.value);
            if (+value <= max && +value >= min) {
              props.onChange({
                target: {
                  name: name,
                  value: +value,
                },
              });
            }
          };
        
          const minus = () => {
            value > min &&
              onChange({
                target: {
                  name: name,
                  value: +value - 1,
                },
              });
          };
          const plus = () => {
            value < max &&
              onChange({
                target: {
                  name: name,
                  value: +value + 1,
                },
              });
          };
          return (
            <div className={["input-number mb-3", props.outerClassName].join(" ")}>
              <div className="input-group">
                <div className="input-group-prepend">
                  <span className="input-group-text minus" onClick={minus}>
                    -
                  </span>
                </div>
                <input
                  min={min}
                  max={max}
                  name={name}
                  pattern="[0-9]*"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder={placeholder ? placeholder : "0"}
                  value={`${prefix}${value}${suffix}${
                    isSuffixPlural && value > 1 ? "s" : ""
                  }`}
                  onChange={onChange}
                />
                <div className="input-group-append">
                  <span className="input-group-text plus" onClick={plus}>
                    +
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
        
        Number.defaultProps = {
          min: 1,
          max: 1,
          prefix: "",
          suffix: "",
        };
        
        Number.propTypes = {
          value: propTypes.oneOfType([propTypes.string, propTypes.number]),
          onChange: propTypes.func,
          placeholder: propTypes.string,
          isSuffixPlural: propTypes.bool,
          outerClassName: propTypes.string,
        };
```

and this is my input date component code I have tried the input component works well, :

```js
    import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
    import propTypes from "prop-types";
    
    import { DateRange } from "react-date-range";
    
    import "./index.scss";
    import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css"; // main css file
    import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css"; // theme css file
    
    import formatDate from "utils/formatDate";
    import iconCalendar from "assets/images/icon/icon-calendar.svg";
    
    export default function Date(props) {
      const { value, placeholder, name } = props;
      const [isShowed, setIsShowed] = useState(false);
      const datePickerChange = (value) => {
        const target = {
          target: {
            value: value.selection,
            name: name,
          },
        };
        props.onChange(target);
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
        return () => {
          document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
        };
      });
    
      const refDate = useRef(null);
      const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
        if (refDate && !refDate.current.contains(event.target)) {
          setIsShowed(false);
        }
      };
    
      const check = (focus) => {
        focus.indexOf(1) < 0 && setIsShowed(false);
      };
    
      const displayDate = `${value.startDate ? formatDate(value.startDate) : ""}${
        value.endDate ? " - " + formatDate(value.endDate) : ""
      }`;
    
      return (
        <div
          ref={refDate}
          className={["input-date mb-3", props.outerClassName].join(" ")}
        >
          <div className="input-group">
            <div className="input-group-prepend bg-gray-900">
              <span className="input-group-text">
                <img src={iconCalendar} alt="icon calendar" />
              </span>
            </div>
            <input
              readOnly
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              value={displayDate}
              placeholder={placeholder}
              onClick={() => setIsShowed(!isShowed)}
            />
    
            {isShowed && (
              <div className="date-range-wrapper">
                <DateRange
                  editableDateInputs={true}
                  onChange={datePickerChange}
                  moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
                  onRangeFocusChange={check}
                  ranges={[value]}
                />
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    Date.propTypes = {
      value: propTypes.object,
      onChange: propTypes.func,
      placeholder: propTypes.string,
      outerClassName: propTypes.string,
    };
```

I have tried the inpudate component to run well, as well as the input number, but if I combine these components I have an error did i miss something, and I tried to combine these components on the bookingform page but when I tried on the browser I experienced the above error.

My code is in the Booking Form:

```js
        import React, { Component } from "react";
        
        import propTypes from "prop-types";
        
        import Button from "elements/Button";
        import { InputNumber, InputDate } from "elements/Form";
        
        export default class BookingForm extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              data: {
                duration: 1,
                date: {
                  startDate: new Date(),
                  endDate: new Date(),
                  key: "selection",
                },
              },
            };
          }
        
          updateData = (e) => {
            this.setState({
              ...this.state,
              data: {
                ...this.state.data,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
              },
            });
          };
        
          componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
            const { data } = this.state;
        
            if (prevState.data.date !== data.date) {
              const startDate = new Date(data.date.startDate);
              const endDate = new Date(data.date.endDate);
              const countDuration = new Date(endDate - startDate).getDate();
              this.setState({
                data: {
                  ...this.state.data,
                  duration: countDuration,
                },
              });
            }
        
            if (prevState.data.duration !== data.duration) {
              const startDate = new Date(data.date.startDate);
              const endDate = new Date(
                startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + +data.duration - 1)
              );
              this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                data: {
                  ...this.state.data,
                  date: {
                    ...this.state.data.date,
                    endDate: endDate,
                  },
                },
              });
            }
          }
          startBooking = () => {
            const { data } = this.state;
            this.props.startBooking({
              _id: this.props.itemDetails._id,
              duration: data.duration,
              date: {
                startDate: data.date.startDate,
                endDate: data.date.endDate,
              },
            });
            this.props.history.push("/checkout");
          };
        
          render() {
            const { data } = this.state;
            const { itemDetails } = this.props;
            console.log(this.state);
            return (
              <div className="card bordered" style={{ padding: "60px 80px" }}>
                <h4 className="mb-3">Start Booking</h4>
                <h5 className="h2 text-teal mb-4">
                  ${itemDetails.price}{" "}
                  <span className="text-gray-500 font-weight-light">
                    per {itemDetails.unit}
                  </span>
                </h5>
        
                <label htmlFor="duration">How long you will stay?</label>
                <InputNumber
                  max={30}
                  suffix={" night"}
                  isSuffixPlural
                  onChange={this.updateData}
                  name="duration"
                  value={data.duration}
                />
                <label htmlFor="date">Pick a date</label>
                <InputDate onChange={this.updateData} name="date" value={data.date} />
                <h6
                  className="text-gray-500 font-weight-light"
                  style={{ marginBottom: 40 }}
                >
                  You will pay{" "}
                  <span className="text-gray-900">
                    ${itemDetails.price * data.duration} USD
                  </span>{" "}
                  per{" "}
                  <span className="text-gray-900">
                    {data.duration} {itemDetails.unit}
                  </span>
                </h6>
        
                <Button
                  className="btn"
                  hasShadow
                  isPrimary
                  isBlock
                  onClick={this.startBooking}
                >
                  Continue to Book
                </Button>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
        
        BookingForm.propTypes = {
          itemDetails: propTypes.object,
          startBooking: propTypes.func,
        };
```

I encountered this error and tried to fix it, but couldn't find a solution to the problem

I use react js to create a staycation website, when I want to display the InputNumber and InputDate components I experience an error like the title above, in the componentDidUpdate section, I have tried tweaking the code but it hasn't worked, but when I omit the componentDidUpdate part, the inputdate and inputnumber components run.
I encountered this error and tried to fix it, but couldn't find a solution to the problem

I use react js to create a staycation website, when I want to display the InputNumber and InputDate components I experience an error like the title above, in the componentDidUpdate section, I have tried tweaking the code but it hasn't worked, but when I omit the componentDidUpdate part, the inputdate and inputnumber components run.

I encountered this error and tried to fix it, but couldn't find a solution to the problem

I use react js to create a staycation website, when I want to display the InputNumber and InputDate components I experience an error like the title above, in the componentDidUpdate section, I have tried tweaking the code but it hasn't worked, but when I omit the componentDidUpdate part, the inputdate and inputnumber components run.

Comment: please, put it in codesanbox.io

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-rosalind-bld6g?file=/src/parts/BookingForm.js

Comment: what is your version of 'react-date-range' ? I try to config your project imports (Could not find dependency: 'date-fns' relative to '/node_modules/react-date-range/dist/components/DayCell/index.js')

Comment: reproduce your error in code sandbox without unnecessary code or components

Comment: I have installed it npm i react-date-range

Comment: https://github.com/sulkifli27/Project-React-Fullstack-Staycation

Comment: it is my project on github

Comment: I have run it. How do I reproduce the error on a running project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227317/discussion-between-daniil-loban-and-sul-kifli).